# How do I define a namespace for query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I use several namespaces in my Google Cloud Datastore

When running:

```
 require "google/cloud/datastore"

 project_id = "PROJECT_ID"
 datastore = Google::Cloud::Datastore.new project: project_id
 ...
 query = Google::Cloud::Datastore::Query.new
 query.kind "Task"
 tasks = datastore.run query
```

it only retrieves entities from 'default' namespace

For example in Python you can define namespace this way:

```
dataclient = datastore.Client("PROJECT_ID", "NAMESPACE")
```

But I can't find a way to do it by Ruby. And I haven't find anything useful in sources as well.

Comment: Looks like there's a PR on this subject from a year ago and I think they've added it.  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/issues/404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked Google on this and they've sent me an example:

```
# Datastore service client
datastore = Google::Cloud::Datastore.new

# Create a new entry with a namespace
entry = datastore.entity "kind", namespace: "test-namespace" do |entry|
  entry["name"]  = "YOURNAME"
end

# Save in datastore
datastore.save entry

# Query a namespaced entry
query = Google::Cloud::Datastore::Query.new
query.kind "kind"
datastore.run query, namespace: "test-namespace"
```